# what is the '[' in Regex in this context ( 2 problems)

Tags: javascript, regex

My final Regex (Updated):

`^[A-z0-9]*([\.]?\w*)*[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]([\.]?\w+)+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]$`

**1st Question**

I know that the square brackets `[]` are used for character set/class, but what I don't understand is that why it does not need a closing bracket, and causes my Reg-ex to act weirdly. For example here it is originally

```
[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9][\.?[A-Za-z0-9+]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]
Matches ----> reg.ex.email@gmail.com
```

Notice that the second `[` before the `\.` as well as the sixth `[` before the second `\.` Those two does not have any closing brackets. I also know that the ? mean zero or one of the preceding element. When I remove the bracket `9]*\.?[\w` the regex does not recgnize the `reg.` part of the string. I also tried adding a closing bracket `[\.?[\w+]]`, `[\.?][\w+]`, but it also causes the same behavior, note that the first one `[\.?[\w+]]` causes it not to recognize the string at all. Can anyone help explain this behavior?

**2nd Question**

Base upon the above Regex I am using the JavaScript regex to test my string. And I don't know why the test is passing even though only part of the string pass the test. Some of my test cases

```
reg@asld@fja.com
reg.exp.email@gmial@gmail.com
reg.exp.email@gm@il.com
reg.exp.themail@gmail.com
```

*I should clarify only `reg.exp.themail@gmail.com` should pass*

If you go to [this site](http://regexpal.com/) and past my regex and test string you can see what I mean. In my javascript I have this

```
var inputVal = $(this).val();       
    var re = /[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9][\.?[A-Za-z0-9+]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]/;
    if (!re.test(inputVal)) {
        $("#emailValidate").css({"display": "inline-block", "color":"red","margin-top":"4px"});          
    } else {
        $("#emailValidate").css("display", "none");
    }
```

Which the test case above pass. Any idea on this one?

Comment: As Sniffer says below, as written the '[' chars that directly follow the '?' chars in your regex are being interpreted as character literals, not special characters.  You could make this more clear by including a '\' in front of them and it shouldn't change the behavior.

Comment: ooooooooooohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, so I should remove the `[` after the `?`

Comment: I think you made a typo in your first regex. `^[A-z0-9]*([\.]?\w+)+[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]([\.]?\w+)+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]$` should be `[A-z0-9]*[\.]?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9][\.]?[A-Za-z0-9+]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]` but it could also be `[A-z0-9]*[.]?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9][.]?[A-Za-z0-9+]+[.][A-Za-z]{3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to first question

Including an open bracket `[` inside a character class is fine, and it doesn't create another character class inside the first one. This is why it is accepted to include it without escaping inside the character class.

### Answer to second question

You need to enclose your pattern between start-of-line `^` and end-of-line `$` anchors so it matches the entire input string and not parts of it like this:

```
^[A-z0-9]*[\.?[\w+]+[A-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9][\.?[A-Za-z0-9+]+\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]$
|                                                                                   |
Start-Of-Line                                                             End_Of_Line
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dK5rS2)

Comment: ok so apparently using the site did not work, but adding it into my java script worked.

Comment: @JackThor Everything is working fine, check the demo link I posted at the end of the answer. Thank you for accepting.

Comment: Wow that site is way better than the one I found. Nice. Thumb up for the awesome link.

Comment: Just bear in mind that **Java** Regex _requires_ you to escape opening square brackets in character classes like `\[` - this is for anyone that thinks this answer applies to all regex flavors...

Comment: @Code Jockey - More importantly, its because Java uses balance square brackets as it allows nested classes and has special meta-char inside classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it was already answered, but ^$ alone don't answer all MY questions. The 2 '[' characters are still useless. For example the first part of the regex (before @) allows only maximum 1 dot in the email address, and the only thing that makes it match with multiple dots is the extra '[' but that shouldn't have this effect. I think now I found what it was supposed to be in the first place:

```
^[A-z0-9]*(\.?\w+)+@...
```

The + after the w also had no effect in the original regex in my opinion when it was inside [] and not () as above.
Or if Jack wants only match exactly 2 dots then:

```
^[A-z0-9]*(\.\w+){2}@...
```

I just don't believe that that extra '[' and the '+' inside [] makes it a reliable pattern. Please correct me sniffer if I am wrong.

Comment: Yep those where some of the problem I had. Based on the the answer and link that Sniffer gave me I was able to make a better regex. Please see my edit above.